# Prokka + table2asn (NCBI submission)

Tags: sequence-annotation, text-processing, ncbi

I have a couple of MAGs of interest that I am trying to submit to the NCBI (with annotations).

The process of submitting the annotations is rather challenging to me. I have the output of Prokka, which includes multiple files, but the one I think I need is the .gff (which is GFF3 format).

The NCBI website descibes how to obtain the required file format (.sqn) from .gff files (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/genomes_gff/). I downloaded the required file (table2asn), and ran the following code:

```
"table2asn" -M n -Z -J -c w -t "template.sbt" -V b -j "[organism=Organism] [strain=strain] [gcode=11]" -i "fasta.fna" -f "annotations.gff" -o output.sqn
```

However, I got an error:
`GFF annotation requires locus tags, which are missing from one or more genes, so the command line argument -locus-tag-prefix is needed.` Which was a bit strange, since I could see that the original file had a locus_tag entry. The format liiked kind of like this:

```
S6C7    Prodigal:002006 CDS 244817  246085  .   -   0   ID=AJNLIECJ_06723;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal:002006,similar to AA sequence:ISfinder:ISNpu7;locus_tag=AJNLIECJ_06723;product=IS701 family transposase ISNpu7
S6C7    Prodigal:002006 CDS 246142  246702  .   -   0   ID=AJNLIECJ_06724;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal:002006;locus_tag=AJNLIECJ_06724;product=hypothetical protein
```

Anyway, I added `-locus-tag-prefix AJNLIECJ` to my code, which at least got me an output, but now the output is a touch weird:

```
 gene            complement(246142..246702)
                 /locus_tag="AJNLIECJ_006724"
 CDS             complement(246142..246702)
                 /locus_tag="AJNLIECJ_006724"
                 /inference="ab initio prediction:Prodigal:002006"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="hypothetical protein"
                 /protein_id="AJNLIECJ:AJNLIECJ_06724"
```

So basically, the /protein_id is repeated, and sometimes the numbers between locus and protein ID don't even match (some of the protein ids 'go ahead' for some reason).

My thoughts:

1. I have no idea how to fix this
2. Is it even necessary to fix it? Since all NCBI protein IDs tend to be in a consistent format anyway, so no matter what I add, it will get updated.
3. Should I remove the /protein_id field? How?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi @Laura, contact the NCBI Helpdesk. They will respond with the exact answer within 1 day and can be within a few hours. You can copy paste, or just cite this question on the request form.